# How to change a column in pandas dataframe to uppercase when it already has some uppercase values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, uppercase, lowercase

I am new to Python and StackOverflow.

I am trying to convert some values in a column `use_ab` of my dataframe:

Here is what my column looks like:

```
df['use_ab'].value_counts()

False    534167
FALSE     15222
True      12724
TRUE       1023
```

What I want to do is convert all values in Upper case.

I tried this code:

```
df['use_ab'] = df['use_ab'].str.upper()
```

It converts "True" and "False" into Uppercase and the rest in NaN values and gives me this output:

```
FALSE    15222
TRUE      1023
```

Please help me to convert this column to Uppercase.

Comment: Looks like you have an object column which is capable of holding all different objects, and in this case holds the two strings `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'` as well as the two Boolean values `True` and `False`. Since the Boolean values are not strings the `.str.upper` methods coerces them to `NaN` after the change

Comment: The values `True` and `False` are not strings and will NOT get converted to uppercase. They are Boolean. Do you want to convert the Boolean value of `True` and `False` to uppercase `TRUE` and `FALSE` ?

Comment: **You have a mixed column of both string and boolean values and its `dtype` is almost surely 'object'** - you should check, and please confirm.

Solution: You can (and should) specify the dtype of a problematic column when you read it with `pd.read_csv()`, also specify ALL the true and false values, at read-time. Use `pd.read_csv(..., dtype=..., true_values=..., false_values=...)`

Comment: is your column actually `TRUE` `False` ? if so use `df['use_ab'].map(pd.eval)` so it is evaulated as a boolean type object as opposed to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have a mixed column of both string and boolean values** (and maybe some other things too), **and its `dtype` is almost surely 'object'** - you should check, and please confirm.

**Solution:** You can (and should) specify the dtype of a problematic column when you read it in, also specify ALL the true and false values, at read-time:

```
pd.read_csv(..., dtype={'use_ab': bool}),
    true_values=['TRUE','True',True], false_values=['FALSE','False',False])
```

Note in particular that **string `'False'` and bool `False` are not the same thing!** and trying to use .str does not convert the bools

Re: `df.dtypes`. The dtype of your column doesn't seem to be string, but it doesn't seem to be to boolean either, since the string accessor `.str.upper()` is throwing away most of your 'False' values, as `value_counts()` proves.

Also, since your series obviously has NaNs and you need to count they're not being mishandled, use `.value_counts(..., dropna=False)` to include them.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.Series(['True',np.nan,'FALSE','TRUE',np.nan,'False',False,True,True])

# Now note that the dtype is automatically assigned to pandas 'object'!
>>> df.dtype
dtype('O')

>>> df.value_counts(dropna=False)
True     2
NaN      2
FALSE    1
TRUE     1
True     1
False    1
False    1
dtype: int64
```

See how **mistakenly trying to use `.str.upper()` accessor on this mixed column is trashing those values that are actually bools**, while case-transforming the strings:

```
>>> df.str.upper()
0     TRUE
1      NaN
2    FALSE
3     TRUE
4      NaN
5    FALSE
6      NaN  <-- bool True coerced to NaN!
7      NaN  <-- bool False coerced to NaN!
8      NaN  <-- bool False coerced to NaN!
dtype: object
```

Comment: Vaibhav: this is not an "effort", it's the right solution, for general mixed data. Coercing dtypes and throwing away much of your data is bad bad bad.

Comment: @VaibhavGhildiyal this should be the accepted solution for your intended use case.

Comment: @smci Yes you are right. Its dtype was object and this is the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want this column to be of type `bool(ean)` or `str` you could do

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'use_ab': [False] * 534167 + ['FALSE'] * 15222 + [True] * 12724 + ['TRUE'] * 1023})

# get boolean series
In [3]: df['use_ab'].astype(bool)
Out[3]:
0         False
1         False
2         False
3         False
4         False
          ...
563131     True
563132     True
563133     True
563134     True
563135     True
Name: use_ab, Length: 563136, dtype: bool

# get string series
In [4]: df['use_ab'].astype(str).str.upper()
Out[4]:
0         FALSE
1         FALSE
2         FALSE
3         FALSE
4         FALSE
          ...
563131     TRUE
563132     TRUE
563133     TRUE
563134     TRUE
563135     TRUE
Name: use_ab, Length: 563136, dtype: object
```

Answer (score -2):

You can change the data type in the first column so you can perform such operation, assuming that the first column header is 'use_ab'

```
df['use_ab'] = df['use_ab'].astype(str)
```

now those boolean's type values will become string, now you can

```
df['use_ab'] = df['use_ab'].str.upper()
```

Comment: Vaibhav: this is not the general answer: it mangles bools in a mixed column (dtype='object'), like you apparently have, which is exactly what `read_csv()` gives you when you mix string, bool, int, categorical etc. You still never stated your dtype! This answer will mislead all the people with dataframes in that general circumstance. Answers on SO are supposed to be reusable resources. Hacking a mixed column instead of reading it in properly the first time is undesirable.

Comment: ...and another thing, you might be able to get away with this on bool but this will mess up categorical, or mixed categorical/string/int columns. So this is a really bad habit to develop.